# Java 5.0 Compiler API?

Tags: java, api, compiler-construction

Is there a Java 5.0 equivalent to the Java 6.0 Compiler API? I'm trying to compile and jar some XmlBean schemas at runtime.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you need to look into those class generation libs: cglib, javaassit etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write the files to disk and call `javac` using System.exec()

<strike>Perhaps</strike> its time to updated to Java 6 or 7.

Comment: I'm tempted to edit this answer to add a `<strike>`-tag around "Perhaps" ;-)

Comment: I think it is to soon to switch to 7.

Comment: I have been watching the developer mail-list for Java 8 and have been tempted to give it a go. ;)

Comment: The *scheduled* proposed final draft (read beta) is May 2012, about seven months way. http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=337

Comment: @MisterSmith: that *might* be (depending on your development schedule and when you plan to deploy), but I've seen **far** to many projects still held back on 1.4.2.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yea I would love to move onto 6 or 7, but client restrictions. Thanks for the answer, though I found another solution that involves a library from the JDK rather than JRE for 5.